# How to specify the format of source_files while creating POD spec?

Tags: ios, swift, cocoapods

I am trying to validate the Pod spec file using the command "pod lib lint", However every-time it throws me an error specify incorrect spec.source_files, I looked into the structure its
[image: Its the file structure]

```
spec.source_files  = 'Dicom/Dicom/**/*.{h,m,swift}'
```

I am looking the way to specify pod spec files sepc.source_files pattern.

Comment: do you use same target for Dicom ?

Comment: yes, I use the same @zeytin